# Android SQLite write error

Tags: android, sqlite

I am writing an android app that works with some SQLite databases at the same time. 
This app works with offline maps databases created by Mobile Atlas Creator. I have another database that holds some metadata about these maps (map_meta_db.sqlitedb). 
All of these databases are stored in external sd card.

All map database files are prefilled so I open them with SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY flag.

But map_meta_db is not read only, so I open it with SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE flag.

I have granted my app to read and write external sd in AndroidManifest.xml:

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

The problem is that I can open all databases and read their data but when I want to insert a new record to map_meta_db, just nothing happens! No exception, No insert!

```
try {
    SQLiteDatabase map_meta_db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(pathToMapMetadataDirectory + MAP_METADATA_DATABASE_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    metaDb.rawQuery(insertSql, null);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "While inserting new record, an error occured:" + e.getMessage());
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Any reason why not using the `insert` method?

Comment: Can you please show the SQL insert statement "insertSql". is it possible that it is the SQL statement itself causing errors? Could be due to a wrong syntax in the SQL command.

Comment: If you `adb shell` and open the db-file on your sdcard with `sqlite3`, can you execute inserts successfully in that case? Also, in `sqlite3`, execute `pragma integrity_check` on your meta-data database.

Comment: insertSql is correct. I copy that and run it with SQLite Database browser without any problem.

Comment: I used `insertOrThrow()` and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider creating something like SQLiteOpenHelper and creating you database like that:

```
private SQLiteDatabase database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
```

where helper is the mentioned implementation SQLiteOpenHelper